# Vue not displaying component on particular route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-router

Basically I want to render the Login component on my Login Route but it is not rendering-

Login component-

```
<template>
<v-app>
     <h1>Login Component</h1>
</v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

Routes.js-

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'
import Register from '@/components/Register'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'register',
    component: Register
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

this is my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I am using vue version-2.6.10 and vue router version-3.1.2..it is also not showing any error please help.

Comment: Do you have a <router-view></router-view> in your App.vue?

Comment: yes sir.. I have it in my app.vue

Comment: The v-app should only be in your app.vue. It should not also be in your login.vue

Comment: Also if you are using Chrome the Vue plugin for Chrome is a godsend for debugging this stuff

Comment: yes i am using vue dev tools but it is showing nothing..also i removed v-app and put it into app.vue still the login component is not rendering. only url is getting changed

Comment: Do you see the content of your App.vue?

Comment: `<template>
<div id="#app">
  <v-app>
  <pgHeader></pgHeader>
  <router-view/>
  </v-app>
</div>
</template>

<script>
`this is my app.vue, i couldnot put it into main question due to restriction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204435/discussion-between-michael-robellard-and-jack-giratina).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you wrap up the `router-view></router-view>` in `<v-content></v-content>` then only your routing will work properly. Otherwise only URL will change and the respective component will not render.